# Is it possible to use Ruby/jRuby/Java on Google App Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, jruby

I understand it possible to do jRuby/Java on Google App Engine, but is I also want to use Ruby on Rails as the front end in that setup, will I be able to?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/

It supports Rails with the current versions: 2.3.5, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.3.10 and 2.3.11, with support for Rails 3 *soon*. It also supports Sinatra.

Comment: when they say soon, how soon do you imagine that would be? Month? 6 months? :)

Comment: According to this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/appengine-jruby/browse_thread/thread/21b6f9e87935836b/af6614db234468aa?show_docid=af6614db234468aa&pli=1 It seems like there is a decent amount of demand for it, so based on how longs its been and the amount of demand.. I'd give it ~3 months.

Comment: ... or tomorrow if someone sends in a patch. It's open source, after all.